# What to use instead of 1k1 Ohm PTC thermistor?

Tags: multimeter, thermistor, over-voltage-protection, ptc

I've got uni-t ut60a damaged. IC was replaced. Two tracks were repaired. The PTC thermistor of 1k1 Ohm is left. Unfortunately it is not easily available, in fact I couldn't find any of these being sold (wmz11a 75HV).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fayfZm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I measured at what voltage clamp transistors pair start to conduct, it is 8.3V.

So my guess is that the device in place of PTC thermistor should have drop voltage = Voltage_applied - 8.3 (at least) in order to not damage anything.

Is there anything which could replace 1k1 Ohm PTC thermistor?

By the way, multimeter is rated 1000V. I would be happy it to work with mains 230V 50Hz.

Comment: A PTC of 1k if you (and the circuit) are not to fussy, otherwise one of 1k and one of 100R in series.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen, the problem in case of two resistors is that if the voltage applied is too high, current will go through clamping transistors and resistors will be fried, if wire in the resistor melts and create a short, the entire IC may be damaged. That's my guess

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen, even 1k PTC is hard to find

Comment: What is your opinion of how the circuit normally functions, and what is V?

Comment: If you can't find it, consider a fuse + resistor. Polyfuse might work, but the voltage rating needs to be considered for it to provide any protection.

Comment: @AnalogKid, 'V' is the barrel socket of multimeter, in which you insert usually red lead, the other one is common (COM) for a black lead. I think I described everything I know about the circuit in the question and comments